# Adding Variables to Directline API response in Botframework

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've successfully request to the **Botframework Directline API** and I getting this example of json **response**:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0000022",
  "timestamp": "2019-10-02T21:09:25.001296Z",
  "channelId": "directline",
  "from": {
    "id": "LuchoBotV1",
    "name": "LuchoBotV1"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "text": "Hay algo mas en que pueda ayudarte?",
  "speak": "Hay algo mas en que pueda ayudarte?",
  "inputHint": "expectingInput",
  "replyToId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0000020"
}
```

Now I'm working in a **waterfall dialog** which asks to the user some personal information (license,address,sales) and I want to add this data to the response and get a json response like this:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0000022",
  ...
  "context": {address: "Street 123", sales: "5000"}
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to **incorporate this information to the API response**. I've been searching in the documentation but I didn't found anything except how to send text.

```
await stepContext.context.sendActivity(messageText, null, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the context to activity's channel data.

**BotFramework SDK v4 (Node)**

```
await stepContext.context.sendActivity({
   text: 'Hello, World!',
   channelData: {
     context: {address: 'Street 123', sales: '5000'}
   }
});
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXX",
  ...
  "text": "Hello, World!",
  "channelData": {
    "context": {"address": "Street 123", "sales": "5000"}
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your solution: `return await stepContext.context.sendActivity({text: msg,context: result});` but the json response is the same. Maybe some part of the code is filtering attributes different to "text"?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my initial answer. You need to put context into the activity's channel data. I've updated my answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending along a variable that stores the user information?

Say you have:

```
var name = 'Anna';
```

You send it along instead of text:

```
await stepContext.context.sendActivity(name);
```

Expected output would be:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXX",
  ...
  "text": "Anna"
}
```

Comment: Two problems with this aproach. First, it is difficult to make a diference between a regular bot text answer and a context variable. Second, the response has to be an object, not a string